# Batch Cypher Import via HTTP stops after 250 records

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am attempting to make thousands of HTTP posts to a Neo4j server in order to create nodes.  The issue is that my script fails after 250 records are inserted.

Endpoint:

`http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher`

POST body:

`{"params":{"props":{"username":"foobar"}},"query":"CREATE (:User {props})"}`

(I am posting with Contenttype set to application/json)

I didn't manage to find anything in my Neo4j server logs. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong log files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you execute your script and how does it fail? (Silently or with some error code/message? Does the script freeze up and become unresponsive, or does your cpu melt into a glorious pool of silicone?) By default there are logs in `data/log/` and `data/graph.db/` that you can look at.

Comment: version is 2.0.0-M06 @WesFreeman

Comment: @jjaderberg, data/graph.db/messages.log and log/console.log log dont seem to show a db transaction history, they just report basic things like 'this' initialized and 'that' is ready

Comment: upgrade to RC1. M06 has some concurrency issues with the labelstore.